# What is a good UI/UX for asking people to pick from two lists?

Tags: mobile, android, mobile-application

I posted this on Stack Overflow, but was told that this would be a better place to post this.

I have an Android app where I want to ask users to pick a tag but it has two levels to it. So essentially I need them to pick from two lists. Currently I have it set up so that it pops up a dialog box with a list and clicking on an item dismisses the dialog box and brings up another with a second list. Also keep in mind that these lists are not static and are fetched from a sever every time. So I don't think an ExpandableListView is the right solution.

I have a feeling that this is not the right UI/UX to do this. In iOS I could open a spinner with two columns but I don't think such a thing exists in Android and is definitely doesn't have a native feeling to it.

So any ideas?

Comment: It's hard to give specific advide without more context. What does the data represent? How are the lists linked? Is one a sub-category of the other?

Comment: @Franchesca You can just think of both of them as a simple list of strings. And yes, one is a subcategory of the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see that as being much different from navigating departments of an e-commerce website:

Here's an example from the [JohnLewis.com](http://m.johnlewis.com/mt/www.johnlewis.com/#page_loaded) mobile website.

First list with categories:

[image]

Second list with sub categories, having a title showing the category you chose, and a way to get back to the first list:

[image]

Comment: The reason I don't want bring up a new page just for this is because I am tagging something and not taking them to a new page. But I did take this idea and put it into a dialog box like I said above. I was just hoping that someone had a more elegant solution

Comment: @sree I didn't mean it to necessarily be a new page, but a kind of 2 step wizard popup where the steps are clearly connected and provide a path, as opposed to two distinct popups which breaks the process up too much.

Comment: Yea, I was kinda thinking along the same lines. Android doesn't have a native way to do this and I was wondering if it would be weird if I created a custom version of this. But I do think that you are right and it is the most ideal way to do it

Answer (score 1):

The modal solution that you described as your current solution does sound awkward - it doesn't provide a clear path and/or hierarchical relationship between the two lists.

Another option would be to treat the selection as a 2-step process that clearly indicates the first level contains major categories, and the second subcategories. Perhaps an off-canvas flyout pattern would work well in this situation.

Another way of approaching this may be to present the first list of options using the spinner that you mentioned, and only revealing the subset (with a spinner) once a choice has been made by the user. Provide a visual/textual indication that the first choice initiated the appearance of the second.